# showing glyphicon carousel-control-right on hovering right carousel-control

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon carousel-control-right"></span></a>
```

I want to show the `glyphicon carousel-control-right` on right only when user hovers over the class `right carousel-control` otherwise it should be hidden.How is this possible please help.
this is the image [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the opacity to 0 so that it's hidden visually but still takes up space in the control link, then set opacity to 1 on `:hover`

```
.carousel-control-right {
  opacity: 0;
}

.right.carousel-control:hover .carousel-control-right {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks MichaelCoker can i do the same using display property?

Comment: @Anonymous the problem with `display: none;` is that when you set that, the icon will disappear entirely from the page, and won't take up space in the `.carousel-control` link. It may or may not work, feel free to try it out. Though what's the advantage over just using opacity?

Comment: what about visibility

Comment: @Anonymous yes, visibility would probably work, it's functionally similar to opacity in your case. But why?